# Maven Java home configuration

Tags: java, maven, java-home

I installed JDK and set up Maven. Call of `mvn -version i get` returns:

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly                                                             This environment variable is needed to run this program                                                                 NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

`$JAVA_HOME` variable is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin` in system variables.

Call of  `%JAVA_HOME%` returns path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin`.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) the `JAVA_HOME` variable must point to the java installation path, not to the `bin` folder.

Change it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

Answer (score 2):

The question is about Windows but I came here trying to solve the problem on Ubuntu. 
I faced a similar problem. I configured `$JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment` 
like `$JAVA_HOME=PATH_TO_JDK` for example `$JAVA_HOME=/home/max/jdk1.8.0_144`

Careful with

- White space after path declaration `$JAVA_HOME=/home/max/jdk1.8.0_144[[_NO_WHITE_SPACE_AFTER_DECLARATION]]`
- Don't put any double apostrophe `$JAVA_HOME="/home/max/jdk1.8.0_144"`
- Don't put /bin e.g `$JAVA_HOME=/home/max/jdk1.8.0_144/bin` <- This is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Yes, original question is about pure windows, but for those who came here wondering about windows linux subsystem WSL, I stumbled across the thing trying to set up my win WSL, to use windows java Open jdk binaries. Though in a while i gave up on that idea. Installed jdk with *'sudo apt install ...'* and then set WSL java home from installed path:

```
root@mypc://# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0+deb9u1-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)

root@mypc://# which java
/usr/bin/java
root@mypc://# realpath /usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

use yours realpath instead.

```
root@mypc://# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
root@mypc://# mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T15:06:16Z)
Maven home: /mnt/c/javaDir/mvn/apache-maven-3.6.2
Java version: 1.8.0_265, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-43-microsoft", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

add export JAVA_HOME=**/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64** to a ~/.bash_profile for this being set every time linux subsystem is lunched.