# On "mvn install" command errors with and without "sudo" ("JAVA_HOME" and "--release" flag respectively)

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, sudo

I have a project that contains the `.pom` file. Based on the instruction, I should run the `mvn install` command first. When I run the command I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling   

Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: invalid flag: --release

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid flag: --release
```

But, when I run the command with `sudo` (`sudo mvn install`), I get the following error:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

However, the result of `mvn -version` command is as follows:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_265, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-42-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

On the other hand, I've added the followings to `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=/usr/share/maven/bin/mvn:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The result of `echo $JAVA_HOME` is:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

and the result of `java -version` is :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~18.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

Besides, I've considered many related posts to my issue, such as [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44680125/3768871), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43496192/3768871), [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44697803/3768871), and [post4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60086303/3768871) (which are about maven in windows, opposite to my Ubuntu OS) or [post5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47243223/3768871) (that I have not the same problem, as I am not on a VM or any problem with `mvn -version`. However, mvn version command points to JRE, but all environment variables have been set correctly to point to the JDK). But, none of them resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a command using `sudo`, the environment variables from your current (non-privileged) shell are NOT passed through to the environment in which the command is run.

Try this:

```
$ export FOO=BAR
$ sudo export
```

and you won't see FOO in the list of variables.

So, when you run `sudo mvn ...` the `JAVA_HOME` setting is not being passed to Maven, and it says so.

If you want to pass all of the environment variables, use `sudo -E` or similar.  This is explained in the manual entry for `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar kind of setting, and that is working. You can try this setting, try restarting the system if possible.

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8`

`export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin`